# Suppose $X_n$ is a record value. Will $F(X_n)$ be a record value as well?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with distribution $F$. We say that a record occurs at time $n,n>0$ and has value $X_n$ if $X_n > \max (X_1,\cdots X_{n-1})$

**Suppose $X_n$ is a record value. Will $F(X_n)$ be a record value as well?** My book says that the record times of the sequence $\{X_1,\cdots,X_n\}$ will be the same as for the sequence $F(X_1),\cdots,F(X_n)$

**Attempt:** $X_n$ is a record value implies $X_n > \max (X_1,\cdots X_{n-1})$. Let the value obtained at time $t$ be $x_n$

> We need to find if $F(X_n) > \max (F(X_1),\cdots,F(X_{n-1}))$

Now, $F(X_n = y) = \mathbb P(X_n \leq y) = \int_{-\infty} ^{y} f_X(x) dx$

$(X_i)'s$ are i.i.d random variables.

$F(X_n)$ will be a record value if $F(X_n) > \max (F(X_1),\cdots,F(X_{n-1}))$ . We are given that $(X_n) > \max ((X_1),\cdots,(X_{n-1}))$

At time $n, F(X_n) \equiv F(X_n = x_n) = \int_{-\infty} ^{x_n} f_X(x) dx$

Since $x_n > \max (x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1}) \implies \int_{-\infty} ^{x_n} f_X(x) dx \ge \int_{-\infty} ^{x_i} f_X(x) dx$

$ \implies F(X_n)$ must be the record value as well for $i<n$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What is it about an increasing function that prevents it from having a record value?

Comment: @DavidK $F$ can have a record value $=1$ somewhere in between and not at $\infty$ in some specific cases only. No?

Comment: From what I see here, a record value just has to be at the end of a sequence in which it is the greatest value. I don't see any requirement of what that value should be, even for a distribution function. Surely you can have a sequence of values that are all less than $1$ and the greatest value in the sequence occurs last.

Comment: @DavidK Aah okay. I have edited my answer. Could you see if the solution is correct?

Comment: My first impression was yes, looking at that, obviously it's true. My second thought was, is it possible that $X_n >X_i$ but $F(X_n) = F(X_i)$? But I can't see how unless the probability of $X_i < X \leq X_n$ is zero for any new independent $X$ with distribution $F$. I don't know if that's enough to say $F(X_n)$ **must** be a record, but it seems to be at least enough to say that $F(X_n)$ is a record with probability $1.$ (And maybe it is just plain true, not only with probability $1$, and I am just not seeing the correct interpretation.)